# Screen Resolution coming low

Tags: display-resolution

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Wipro Laptop and everything is working fine apart from my screen resolution which is coming low. How can I make it normal resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Ubuntu logo in the upper left corner of the screen, type "resolution" and click the display. This will bring up a settings screen that allows you to set the resolution. For more details see video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQ_N-mQCmIc).